# How do I change keyboard geometry from 104 to 105 keys?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and I have been experiencing the following issue with former releases as well.

I am using a German keyboard layout. However, I am missing the key to display the pipe- / inequality-signs (which on German keyboards is supposed to be left to the <kbd>Y</kbd> key).

I already tried to add or remove different German keyboard layouts using system settings but non of the layouts include this key. The best I could get so far is to have access to t he following symbols: `»` and `«`. However, these are not the appropriate German inequality signs plus the pipe symbol is missing.

See this screenshot of my German keyboard layout:

[image]

Comment: In the picture you show, it looks like the < and > are available with shift+alt gr. The lack of a pipe sounds like a bad flaw in the design. Have you looked at other German language keyboards (eg Swiss German or Austria) to see if any of them are in fact a better match?

Comment: Indeed, shift+alt gr leads to the following symbols: `›` and `‹`. Again, they seem to be not the correct inequation symbols. The correct ones should be way larger. Also alternative German language keyboards are missing the symbols.

Comment: Yeah, that's a single quotation mark. Certainly useful for some styles of writing German, but it's hard to get by without >, < and |.

Comment: You can try to modify the keyboard layout as I did for my Spanish keyboard. http://rlog.rgtti.com/2014/05/01/how-to-modify-a-keyboard-layout-in-linux/ (PS: wow, a keyboard layout that seems as bad as the Italian one!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might be, that the wrong keyboard model is selected. To view currently installed keyboard model issue:

```
setxkbmap -print | grep geometry
```

If you see `pc104` there you will have a 104 key layout where the <kbd>> < |</kbd> key is not defined.

In order to use a typical German 105 keys keyboard, you have to choose the "pc105" type, labeled "Generische PC-Tastatur mit 105 Tasten (Intl)" in the German localization of Ubuntu on installation. To change this later you can issue

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

or edit `/etc/default/keyboard` as root. My file looks as following:

```
# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE

# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.

XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="de"
XKBVARIANT="nodeadkeys"
XKBOPTIONS=""

BACKSPACE="guess"
```

On Xfce you can change the setting for your user only as well. The respective option is in [Settings/Keyboard Settings/Layout](http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-settings/keyboard). Nevertheless, since I don't use Unity or Gnome, I have no idea where the respective setting is hidden there (if someone knows: please update this answer).

Comment: It appears the keyboard mode setting can not be changed from Unity GUI (at least I have not found it).

Comment: Simple and plain. The `dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` command was the solution.