# Keyboard doesn't work on boot

Tags: drivers, keyboard

I have a Corsair K70 RGB keyboard and when I reboot the computer I need to unplug and plug back in the keyboard because it doesn't work at all.

I installed this software and driver [ckb-next](https://github.com/mattanger/ckb-next) to be able to use my Corsair mouse on Ubuntu (Corsair Glaive-RGB) since it wasn't working at all. This software also install a driver to use the K70 RGB Keyboard.

But with or without it I need to unplug and plug back in the keyboard to use it. Is there anything to do except changing keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

From cbk-next git did you tried this:

> Problem: Keyboard doesn't work in BIOS, doesn't work at boot Solution:
>   Some BIOSes have trouble communicating with the keyboard. They may
>   prevent the keyboard from working correctly in the operating system as
>   well. First, try booting the OS without the keyboard attached, and
>   plug the keyboard in after logging in. If the keyboard works after the
>   computer is running but does not work at boot, you may need to use the
>   keyboard's BIOS mode option. BIOS mode can be activated using the poll
>   rate switch at the back of the keyboard. Slide it all the way to the
>   position marked "BIOS". You should see the scroll lock light blinking
>   to indicate that it is on. (Note: Unfortunately, this has its own
>   problems - see Known Issues. You may need to activate BIOS mode when
>   booting the computer and deactivate it after logging in).

source:https://github.com/mattanger/ckb-next#linux

Comment: Yeah when you go on their GitHub page they say that they doesn't maintain the driver anymore and they redirect me to the GitHub I gave above to ckb-next since they kept improving the drivers.

Answer (score 0):

It's an old thread, but showed up first. I seem to have fixed the issue for me.

Some info: Corsair k70 red qwerty (latest firmware as of writing this), Pop OS, kernel 5.16, SDDM, plasma 5.22.5. I use ckb-next, but that doesn't load until logged in. I use Windows > ICUE to update to the latest firmware.

**So, the fix: settings > input > keyboard > hardware > model

Changing it from generic 101-key to generic 104-key**

You could maybe try some others, might work, no idea why. If you use the default DE (Gnome), I assume the steps will be similar.

[How do I change keyboard geometry from 104 to 105 keys?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/461748/how-do-i-change-keyboard-geometry-from-104-to-105-keys)
This thread shows how you might be able to do it through console. Didn't need to try myself.

I remember other distros putting this on generic 104 and I had no issues with those, but Pop selected generic 101 (which works, but only after logging in).

Comment: Since this is a Ubuntu only site and that is a Pop OS answer it may not even work.